IntelliJ IDE Cannot Find javax.annotation.processing.Generated Symbol While mvn test Works Correctly
I am having a problem with my project configuration and running the program and unit test. When running with mvn test the JUnit test executes propertly, but when executing from within the IntelliJ IDE, it throws:
## JPS Errors Summary
java:ERROR:cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class Generated
  location: package javax.annotation.processing; file: /home/api/target/generated-sources/annotations/org/example/core/user/model/User_.java at (3:35)
java:ERROR:cannot find symbol
  symbol: class Generated; file: /home/api/target/generated-sources/annotations/org/example/core/user/model/User_.java at (6:2)

Here are the POM dependencies on Datanucleus:
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.persistence-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.annotation</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.annotation-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.2</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.datanucleus</groupId>
    <artifactId>datanucleus-core</artifactId>
    <version>5.2.11</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.datanucleus</groupId>
    <artifactId>datanucleus-rdbms</artifactId>
    <version>5.2.11</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.datanucleus</groupId>
    <artifactId>datanucleus-api-jpa</artifactId>
    <version>5.2.8</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.datanucleus</groupId>
    <artifactId>datanucleus-jpa-query</artifactId>
    <version>5.0.5</version>
</dependency>
<!-- Plugins -->
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.datanucleus</groupId>
    <artifactId>datanucleus-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>5.2.1</version>
    <configuration>
        <api>JPA</api>
        <persistenceUnitName>test-pu</persistenceUnitName>
        <log4jConfiguration>${basedir}/log4j.properties</log4jConfiguration>
        <verbose>true</verbose>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>process-classes</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>enhance</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.8.1</version>
    <configuration>
        <source>1.8</source>
        <target>1.8</target>
        <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
        <annotationProcessorPaths>
            <path>
                <groupId>javax.annotation</groupId>
                <artifactId>javax.annotation-api</artifactId>
                <version>1.3.2</version>
            </path>
        </annotationProcessorPaths>
    </configuration>
</plugin> 


Make sure that the Intellij project java version is set to the correct version.  https://www.baeldung.com/intellij-change-java-version

If mvn test is working, then executing the same phase from IntelliJ should be working as well. Are you having IntelliJ delegate build tasks to Maven (e.g., by creating a run configuration that executes a Maven phase/goal)?

@quarks Note IntelliJ pulls many project configurations from the POM(s). I see you've configured the maven-compiler-plugin to use 1.8 for the source and target. If you're using Java 11, then try setting those properties to 11 (also consider configuring release instead of source and target).

@Slaw I mean the "Build Project" in IntelliJ is failing, and thus, it won't run using IntelliJ, and btw, I am also using Jetbrains Fleet for more smooth and lightweight Java programming.

Even with Fleet, most if not all build tasks should be delegating to the build tool (Maven in this case).

The solution is to downgrade the JVM from 11 to 8. Then running mvn datanucleus:enhance first before running the IDE build (e.g. run or test). For maven, the enhancing runs automatically.
